# Dispersion of light without deviation

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, dispersion

Why do we have dispersive angle in dispersion without deviation if there is no deviation from the original path?

Comment: It is advised only to write what is relevant to question in the topic.

Comment: The the frequency dependence of the refractive index is called chromatic dispersion. The "dispersive angle" is a result of chromatic dispersion. The amount of deviation depends on both the angle of incidence *and* the refractive index.  The lack of deviation in the case of perpendicular incidence is just a very special, singular, case of the arbitrary incidence angle.

Comment: To check whether deviation is happening- check whether the emergent ray of the mean colour, that is, yellow is parallel to the incident ray. In dispersion and no deviation, there will be a dispersive angle between the red-light ray and the violet light ray. However, the yellow-light ray will come out parallel to the incident ray.